# What is the executable file of pipe operator / pipe character (vertical bar character "|") in linux/unix system

Tags: linux, shell, unix, syntax

Usually, we run commands in a terminal/tty/command window in the Linux system.
If we run `ls -l`, we know that we actually execute a file named `ls` located `/bin`.  The full path being `/bin/ls`.

There are a lot of talks about pipeline in *nix-like system.  What is the exact executable file located in the system corresponding to`|`?  Even if the pipeline function is built in the system, there should be a piece of code be found. I cannot find documentation about that. It's not very easy to pick up the answers from the Google's result page.

I have read some elementary information about pipeline creation or something related to pipeline programming in the C language.  Those look very different from the behaviour of `|`. Is the pipe operator ("|") in the shell doing the same thing as the examples in the elementary C programming books describe?

Besides the `|`, pipe character, what are the corresponding files for `>`, and `<` ?

Update 1:
After get some answers from yours posts below, I think my original skeleton of the pipe mechanism is called "faked pipe" from http://www.linfo.org/pipe.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The characters `<`, `>`, `>>`, `|` are not processes in the same sense as executables like `ls`.  Rather, they are instructions to the shell which modify the ways in which other processes are created.

First, note that however you type in your Linux commands, you're not really directly interacting with the Linux operating system itself.  You're using a program called a shell - most likely `/bin/bash`, but there are several different shell programs available, most of which operate in much of the same basic ways.  The main purpose of a shell is to interpret your input in order to start up other processes.  This involves the Linux system call [`fork`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) (or possibly `clone`) to create a new process as a child process of the shell process, followed by the system call [`execve`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) to have that child process load and run the specified program with the specified arguments.

The shell might do various bits of interpretation on the input to determine what the actual program and arguments will be, like substituting command aliases, substituting environment variables, and expanding `~`, `*`, and `[]` characters.  Similarly, the `<`, `>`, `>>`, and `|` symbols have special meaning to the shell, but rather than modifying the executable name or arguments, they modify exactly how the child process is created.

A Linux process normally begins life with three "file handles" open: standard input, standard output, and standard error.  By default, child processes of the shell will use the same input/output/error as the shell, meaning that they can get input from the keyboard via the same mechanism as the shell, and output from the process appears in the same window.  When the `<`, `>`, and `>>` redirection instructions are used, the shell will modify the file handles for the process in between the `fork` and the `execve` so that before the executable is even started in the child, one or more of its default file handles will actually read from/write to the named files.

When the "pipe" character `|` is used, the shell will start up two child processes at about the same time, but with the output of the first process connected up to the input of the second process.  This involves the system call [`pipe`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe), to create a pair of file handles where writing to one handle just puts the data into operating system memory until it is read out from the other handle.

So for example,

```
grep 'MAGIC' file1.txt | sort
```

will (not necessarily in this order):

1. Create a pair of pipe file handles
2. Create a child process for the `grep` command.
3. Replace the child's standard output file handle to use the write end of the pipe.
4. Begin the `grep` command via `execve`.
5. Create a child process for the `sort` command.
6. Replace the child's standard input file handle to use the read end of the pipe.
7. Begin the `sort` command via `execve`.
8. Wait for the `sort` child process to finish.

In terms of "even if the pipeline function is built in the system, there should be a piece of code be found", you would find the code for interpreting these special shell characters in the code for the shell program.

Comment: very very useful.Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

**The characters you're referring to are *shell operators*, not *executable files*** (e.g., binary files such as `/bin/ls`, a.k.a *external utilities*).

That is, these characters instruct the shell how to *coordinate execution* of *commands* (external utilities, shell builtins, functions, aliases) and *redirect their input/output*.

- **`|` is an instance of a shell *control operator***, which chains execution of multiple commands in a [*pipeline*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02).
- **`<` and `>` are shell *redirection operators*** for redirecting *stdin* input and *stdout* output, respectively.

If your shell is `bash`, consult `man bash`, or, more generally, `man $SHELL`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how the shell handle the | ? how to make performance not bad? if very huge output get from prevoius cmd, how to put those content to the next cmd?

Comment: An entire book is needed to explain how pipe works. I gave some references in my question

Comment: @gfan: I've added a link to the POSIX definition of a pipeline. Generally, pipelines use a _fixed-size buffer_ in order to process large files, relaying data in buffer-sized chunks so as not to consume too much memory at once; to determine the size of this buffer, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11954/54804

Answer (score 4):

There's no file for `|` or `<`. Those are implemented inside the shell. The same goes for `if`, `for`, `while`, `etc`. It couldn't be implemented as an executable because `|` connects executables instructing the shell what it should do about their inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 3):

The pipe is *not* an executable, but a way to have [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (in [pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix))). It is an essential feature (like many others, including files and directories and processes) provided by the [Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel). The relevant [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) is [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), and the [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) page gives more explanations.

An entire book (at least) is needed to answer your question. So we cannot answer here. But I am giving a few references:

Read some book on Linux programming, such as the old [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) book (freely downloadable; it has several chapters related to your question) or something newer. See also the list of [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

Then read some book about operating systems. I recommend [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (freely downloadable; again it has several chapters related to your question).

So you need to spend several days or weeks in reading.

Your shell is using [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) to interpret `|`. For [redirections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) like `>` or `<` it uses [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) or `dup`. Of course a shell uses [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) to create processes, [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) or similar to wait for them, and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) to run programs. [Globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) (see [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)) requires scanning directories with [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) etc and querying file metadata with [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html)... `cd` has to be a shell builtin and uses [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html).

So you also need to read more about [unix shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) (and a good way of understanding them is to write your own tiny shell in C; this is a very common and interesting exercise).

BTW, most unix shells are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). You could study their source code. The [`sash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) shell is a bit buggy, but it is tiny (and very basic!) and its source is quite readable. Of course real practical shells like [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), [zsh](http://zsh.org/), [fish](http://fishshell.com/) have much more features (most of them for convenience), so are more complex, but you can still study their source code since they are free software.

Comment: very very useful. Thanks